# Node JS fs.unlink not working Static folder

Tags: node.js

I have static folder, this:

```
App.use('/getUnity', Express.static(__dirname + '/uax_vr_uploads/unityFiles'));
```

I want delete file in folder, not working this 2 fs.unlink:

```
fs.unlink('http://localhost:3002/getUnity/' + response[0][item].varyant_object, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Deleted');
  }
});
```

OR

```
fs.unlink('http://localhost:3002/uax_vr_uploads/unityFiles/' + response[0][item].varyant_object, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Deleted');
  }
});
```

Console LOG:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'http://localhost:3002/getUnity/file-1590880543263.unity3d'] {
      errno: -2,
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'unlink',
      path: 'http://localhost:3002/getUnity/file-1590880543263.unity3d'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to remove a file from your static folder, then you need to pass a valid OS path name to `fs.unlink()` not a URL that only your server would know about.

If the file on your disk that you're actually trying to remove is this:

```
/uax_vr_uploads/unityFiles/file-1590880543263.unity3d
```

Then, judging by your code, it looks like you want this:

```
fs.unlink('/uax_vr_uploads/unityFiles/' + response[0][item].varyant_object);
```